# I am using datatables.net library for exporting data into pdf and excel but when downloading the data it is aligning in single line

Tags: plugins, datatables-1.10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpeh3.png)

This is my code:-

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable-0').DataTable( {
            "searching": true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            pagingType: "full_numbers",
            orientation: 'landscape',
            pageSize: 'A4', 
            alignment: "center",
            lengthMenu: [
                [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
                [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
            ],
            iDisplayLength: 100,

            buttons: [
                'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'

            ],
        } );
} );
```

This is my code:-

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable-0').DataTable( {
            "searching": true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            pagingType: "full_numbers",
            orientation: 'landscape',
            pageSize: 'A4', 
            alignment: "center",
            lengthMenu: [
                [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
                [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
            ],
            iDisplayLength: 100,

            buttons: [
                'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'

            ],
        } );
} );
```

I am expecting something like this organised data:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfKqU.png)

i don't know how to achieve this, please help me in this question.